# Delete until second forward slash in vim

Tags: vim

I would like to delete `https://` from a url

```
Here is a sentence with the url https://www.google.com.
```

Should be replaced with

```
Here is a sentence with the url www.google.com.
```

I would think the motion is <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> but that doesn't work because <kbd>/</kbd> is a special character.

What is the shortest way to delete `https://` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the count and motion backward, you need `d2t/`. `t`il is a motion, and can be done any count of times. `t2` just means "go to the next 2".

Also, `t`il only goes up until the second slash. If you want to delete the second slash as well, use `f`ind inline as in `d2f/`.